# Как получать информацию о товарах в корзине?

Tags: php, битрикс

Нами было приобретено решение https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/concept... . С помощью которого сделан интернет-магазин. Позднее поступила задача подключения кнопки оплаты в кредит от одного из банков. Штатными средствами битрикса такую кнопку не подключить. С самим подключением в DOM-дереве корзины магазина проблем нет. Кнопка подключена и все работает.
Вопрос заключается в следующем. Как можно отслеживать, какие товары были добавлены в корзину? А затем добавлять их в опции получения кредита.

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно отслеживать, какие товары были добавлены в корзину? А затем добавлять их в опции получения кредита.

По всей видимости нужно написать свой обработчик события обновления/добавления в корзину https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/events/

Но скорее всего в вашем случае нужно работать с сущностью заказа, а не корзиной — ведь кредит будет оформляться на заказ, а не выборочно на элементы корзины.

Comment: Прошу прощения. С битриксом на данный момент я на "вы". Можете пояснить в чем будет разница при работе с сущностью заказа?

Comment: Лучшая статья на тему как работать с корзиной в D7 здесь https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-basket-bitrix-d7